# Multiple Regex Matches Using Negative Lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

I have this paragraph:

> "This is the next paragraph that contains the code for the master
>   budget and the other master budget. Also it contains only the master
>   budget terms. But only this budget should get matched. But this budget
>   will not get matched".

Here, I'm trying to match only the first occurrence of the word "budget" and skip all the occurrences of budget if it is preceded by "master" or "other master". I'm using negative look-behind for this and have come up with a piece of code that works fine on the website https://regex101.com:

```
p = re.compile(r'((?<!master|master other)\s\bbudget\b)')
test_str = "This is the next paragraph that contains the code for the master budget and the other master budget. Also it contains only the master budget terms. But only this budget should get matched"
re.findall(p, test_str)
```

But I get this error "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern". Any way around this ?

Comment: This is a known [regex101 bug](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/285). There are more :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is because lookbehinds in Python should be of fixed length, and `(?<!master|master other)` length is *not* fixed.

Since

```
(?<!master|master other)
```

is equivalent to

```
(?<!master)(?<!master other)
```

you can change your regex to:

```
((?<!master)(?<!master other)\s\bbudget\b)
```

Comment: Thanks Maroun, I'll try it out.

Comment: There is no need using the outer parentheses. The value is accessed with `match.group(0)` or `match.group()` easily.